# delete a row of a table Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to delete a row of a table.

i get the element of table from my entity "Entite".

in my controller  i have:

```
 public function deleteBuAction($id){


     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
     $entite=$this->get('entite.entiteservice')->findId($id);
            $em->remove($entite);
            $em->persistAndFlush($entite);

    return $this->render("acmeBundle:admin:delete.html.twig");


}
```

in the twig of table :

```
{% for entite in liste %}




                            <tr class="odd gradeX">

                                     <td> {{ entite.nom_entite  }} </td> 
                                     <td> {{ entite.nom_agence  }} </td> 
                                     <td> {{ entite.entite_abrev }} </td>
                                     <td> {{ entite.entite_niveau  }} </td> 
                                     <td>
                                        <a  href=#><img src="{{ asset('bundles/acme/img/modifier.png')}}" width="20" height="20"  /></a>
                                        <a  href={{ path('delete_bu', {'id': entite.id}) }}><img src="{{ asset('bundles/acme/img/delete.png')}}" width="20" height="20" /></a>
                                     </td>
                            </tr>

                    {% endfor %}
```

i get this exception :

```
EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, NULL given.
```

i want to get the same twig of the list of entite not delete.html.twig how can i rest in the same twig .
any help please?

Comment: as the error says `remove` function is expecting an entity object but was given `null` which means `$entite` is null so you have to check why this function is returning null `$this->get('entite.entiteservice')->findId($id)`

Comment: it's not null because get the name of Entite when i do: echo $entite->getNomEntite();

Comment: please how can get the page of confirmation (javascript) when i click on the icone of delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like this

```
         public function deleteBuAction($id){


         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
         $entite = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity')->find($id);
         $em->remove($entite);
         $em->persist($entite);
         $em->flush();

         return $this->render("acmeBundle:admin:delete.html.twig");

        }
```

because your code line

```
         $entite=$this->get('entite.entiteservice')->findId($id);
```

is not fetching the object but for fetching object you will have to used

```
          $entite = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity')->find($id);
```

for getting confirmation alert u should do little more; on your delete link suppose :

```
      <a  href={{ path('delete_bu', {'id': entite.id}) }} onclick="myFunction()" ><img src="{{ asset('bundles/acme/img/delete.png')}}" width="20" height="20" /></a>
```

and in your Javascripts add this

```
     function myFunction() {
            alert("Do u want to delete it ?");
        }
```

Comment: please how can get the page of confirmation (javascript) when i click on the icone of delete?

Answer (score 1):

> @ajeet-varma example

Don't remove and persist the entity. Only remove:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$entity = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity')->find($id);
$em->remove($entity);
$em->flush();
```